# How do I compute row-wise minimum (least) in prestodb?

Tags: presto

I am trying to get the minimum of a couple of fields within a row with presto. In other SQL implementations like MySql this function is called LEAST. What is the equivalent function in Presto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Presto 0.100 you can use [`least`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/comparison.html#least):

```
SELECT LEAST(a, b);
```

For versions prior to that, use this equivalent:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN a > b THEN b ELSE a END);
```